# Remove link/button to Edit item/New item from view, No Code

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to remove all button/links for users to edit item or create item from sharepoint view. Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

**Warning**: if you don't want users to be able to edit/create items, removing buttons will not prevent them from doing so anyway. For example, by using direct link. Instead, you should regulate this by setting up correct permissions.

You can set permissions through Site Actions -> Site Permissions, assigning Read permission level to some or all users. Also you can create a custom permission level (from the same page, click `Permission levels` button on ribbon, and then click *Add a Permission Level* link).

If you want to remove Edit/Create buttons **in addition** to setting permissions, it can be done using Sandboxed No-code Solutions.

Below, I assume that:

1. You're using SharePoint 2010.
2. You want to remove New/Edit buttons from Ribbon (because all the other links and menu options will be removed automatically as soon as you strip *AddListItems* and *EditListItems* permissions).

Now, below is the Custom Action code which will remove buttons "New item" and "Edit item" in all the lists (list views + list display forms) in your site/site collection (that depends on the feature scope):

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"> 
 <CustomAction Id="RemoveRibbonButtons" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon" RegistrationType="ContentType" RegistrationId="0x01">
  <CommandUIExtension>
   <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.New.NewListItem" />
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Manage.EditProperties" />
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.EditItem" />
   </CommandUIDefinitions>
  </CommandUIExtension>
 </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

This can be deployed as Sandboxed No-code Solution (i.e. it doesn't include dll file). This will work perfectly well in Office365 and wherever Sandboxed Solutions are available.

Also, you can achieve this using PowerShell if you have appropriate permissions.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I am not very good with sharepoint permissions. I have such requirement like, there are two groups, Submitter and approver. Once a submitter saves a form then persone from approver groups should be able to edit this. If he rejects it then again submitter should be able to edit it or if he approves it nobody should be able to edit it. Right now I am using custom list in Sharepoint 2010. I am not sure what permissions I should give to these groups.

Comment: Your situation seems to be a perfect task for Workflows. SharePoint Designer Workflows can be created using only SPD (and, if you wish, Visio), without any development. Please, Google about it or post it as a separate question. Here is Technet homepage for SharePoint 2010 Workflows: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff819861.aspx

Comment: And I cannot resist mentioning: your current question hardly seems appropriate. Both Eric and I spent our time for nothing, it seems. And I appeal to you therefore: please, elaborate your questions, and always try to mention not only **what** do you want to achieve, but also, **why** are you trying to achieve this. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Set the view to use no tool bar.  This will hide the option to create items.  Switch the Title column to just Title so they can't dive into the item and edit it.

Though this is security through obscurity, users could still edit and create items if they know the URLs.  It'd be better to just give the users Read permission to the list.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to remove it but i can still edit the item using buttons in ribbon, can we remove them or disable them same way?